# How to change baseurl of revolution slider after moving wordpress app from local to cpanel

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I just moved my wordpress app from my pc to cpanel and I realized the images were not showing. I noticed from the developer console that the img-src were http://localhost...

I already changed the permalink of the app. I also went to revolution slider settings, then import/export/replace and I replaced localhost with my domain name but its still pointing to localhost. Pls what can  do about this

Comment: When you migrate wordpress database, in sql file you have to search all occurrences of old base url and replace them with new base url before importing sql file in new database or you can use plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace

Answer (score 3):

Domain Switch is not free, it requires that you have a currently active license through Envato for $21.

Such a shame for Theme Punch to remove this feature.  It's been causing a lot headaches and wasted time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently changed your domain, you will need to to install a free Rev Slider addon called Domain Switcher. (New to me, I have migrated many sites without it, but the new version may require it.) You find the addon inside of Rev Slider in the dashboard, Slider Revolution > AddOns > DS (Domain Switch). [See Here](https://www.themepunch.com/slider-revolution/domain-switch-addon/)

Answer (score 0):

- Install [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin and activate it.
- Then  search for youroldsite.com and replace with yournewsite.com
  then select all tables.
- NOTE: Make sure that you have checked "Run as Dry run" to see number
  of changes occures before update the database.

Answer (score -1):

Domain switch is a built-in add-on. if you have a license key then you are able to install it. check the process of how to use it to replace the old URL.
Step 1
[image]

Step 2
[image]